# Telegram API - Channel User Count

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-webhook

I like to know how to use telegram API to query number of users that are in a particular channel.
I have checked this but there is no example
https://core.telegram.org/api

I am not trying to create a bot, just looking to present stats about a channel.

Comment: Use [getChatMembersCount](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount) method of BotAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@mymedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051251/telegram-api-channel-user-count#comment83074677_48051251) mentioned, you can use `getChatMembersCount` method via Bot API.

You can find full usage in [this document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), or see following example:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]